# sum weekly range in excel

Tags: excel

I have following data in excel -

```
4/2/2002    -0.018255578
4/3/2002    -0.016528926
4/4/2002    0
4/5/2002    -0.016806723
4/8/2002    0.004273504
4/9/2002    -0.006382979
4/10/2002   0.002141328
4/11/2002   -0.004273504
...
```

I need to sum all entries of 2nd column that fall on Monday. I am using the following formula but it doesn't work-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(WEEKDAY(A2:A15)=2,1,0),B2:B15)
```

A related question - how do I select the dates falling on monday from the given list and copy it to a column with a formula?

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a formula that will do the first question:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(A1:A8)=2)*B1:B8)
```

This assumes that your data starts in A1. Adjust your ranges accordingly. You can also use an array formula:

```
=SUM((WEEKDAY(A1:A8)=2)*B1:B8)
```

I'm not sure that I understand the second part, which may be why your question is getting voted down.

Comment: thanks for your help. 2nd question is basically if I have say 20 dates, I want to print those dates that fall on a monday.

Comment: In that case, I would insert a column that contains the `Weekday` function for each date. Then go to Insert > Table to make a Table (or List if you are on Excel 2003) out of your data. Finally, a simple filtering on the weekday column will hide everything but Mondays. You can then select and copy the visible rows.

Comment: is it possible to do this in one formula. For example, have it create a range/row/column of dates that fall on monday

Comment: the problem is I have a lot of time series of daily returns for past 10 years and I need to compute weekly stats on them. The best option I feel is to copy weekly dates, then run vlookups on the dates to get weekly returns. This approach can be applied to monthly, quarterly etc

Comment: Yes, you can use an Advanced Filter for this. You want to choose the "Copy to another location" option. Make sure to add the weekday column as mentioned above, and then run the Advanced Filter. It is easier to give you a link than to explain it, so go here:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/using-advanced-table-filtering-in-excel-2010.html

Comment: got it. thanks.I am a Matlab guy and used to automating everything which is not always possible in excel.