# SUM values in range with same week & year in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have an [excel sheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AscnAC2LuxnzbpISSv6VReRW7Eo?e=DdcYMg) with hours | week | year in A:C and I would like to calculate "weekly hours" in column D.

[image]

For each unique Week & Year combination the number of hours will be displayed.

**What I tried so far**
I set up unique combination of year&week and then tried to `IF(F2=Unique,SUM(A:A),"false")` but this just added entire hours and not only hours that were equal to the unique value.

Some similar but different questions & answers appear on StackOverflow. This one [sums all data = monday](https://%20%20%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356416/sum-weekly-range-in-excel)

=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(A1:A8)=2)*B1:B8)

I couldnt really find anything where output was going to be written into each of the cells in a column as I need.

**Possible answer**

I think a query that sums values could work, but I am not sure. Appreciate any help.

Again a [shared excel sheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AscnAC2LuxnzbpISSv6VReRW7Eo?e=DdcYMg) on microsoft 360 is also available [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AscnAC2LuxnzbpISSv6VReRW7Eo?e=DdcYMg).

Comment: BTW, Your 28|2015 sum is off.  You show as if they are two separate weeks.  The sum of that week should be 25.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMIFS():

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,B2,C:C,C2)
```

Then copy that formula down.

Or with office 365 we can do the range and it will spill:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,B2:B14,C:C,C2:C14)
```

[image]

Comment: I was just going to post same formula.

Comment: wow. i have to check that out. that was fast

Comment: yup that works. too fast for me to accept the answer but will do so after 5 minutes